# CentOS7サービス登録する際、[Service] ExecStartで複数起動指定したい

Tags: centos, systemd

**CentOS7で、1つのサービス起動したら、5個ぐらいデーモン起動させたいのですが**
・ExecStart欄で、指定ディレクトリ以下全て起動、みたいな指定はできないでしょうか？
・あるいは、複数指定出来ないでしょうか？

・現状

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/hoge
```

---

・試したこと

```
   [Service]
    ExecStart=/opt/hoge
    ExecStart=/opt/hoge2
```

・上記のように書いたら、下記エラーとなりました

> Invalid argument.

---

**追記**
・複数のソケットファイルを動かすことを想定
・/run/go/app/の下に、hoge1.sock と hoge2.sock を作成したい

・hoge1.go

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/fcgi"
)

func handler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(res, "Hello World! 1")
}

func main() {
    os.RemoveAll("/run/go/app/hoge1.sock")
    l, err := net.Listen("unix", "/run/go/app/hoge1.sock")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    fcgi.Serve(l, nil)
}
```

※hoge2.goは、上記で「hoge1」を「hoge2」へ置換

複数起動する場合の手順

```
go build hoge1.go

./hoge1
```

・hoge1.sockファイルが作成されることを確認
※hoge2も同様

・build結果のhoge1 と hoge2 を run-parts でサービス登録
・一旦ソケットファイルを削除して起動させてみたら、hoge1.sockだけ作成されました

Comment: 具体的にはどんなデーモン(プログラム)を動かすことを想定していますか？また、手動でコマンドラインから複数起動する場合の手順はどうなっていますか？(該当のデーモンはそもそも多重起動を想定されているのでしょうか)

Comment: 本文に追記しました。多重起動については、ソケットファイル名を別にすれば複数起動できると思ったのですが…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下でいかがでしょうか?

```
[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/dir
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'for x in *; do ./$x & done'
```

---

`Type=forking` は、昔からあるデーモンのように、

- fork して
- 親プロセスは終了する

というプログラムのためのものです。

一方 `Type=simple` は、fork しない単純なプログラムのためのものです。

`Type=forking` の場合は、systemd は実行したプロセスが子プロセスを残して終了することを期待するのに対して、
`Type=simple` の場合は、systemd は実行したプロセスが終了しないことを期待します。

今回の場合、bash 自体はすぐに終了するため、`Type=forking` としました。

また、bash の `-c` オプションは、その文字列をそのまま実行する、というものです。

- `bash '文字列'`

  その文字列をファイル名として、そのファイルの中身を実行する。
- `bash -c '文字列'`

  その文字列を実行する。

go の compile とは全く無関係です。というか、私のこの回答に go に依存した箇所は一切ありません。

`for x in *; do ./$x & done` は、一行で書くと解りにくいので、以下のように分解できます。

```
for x in *
do
  ./$x &
done
```

カレントディレクトリにある全てのファイルを background で実行しているだけです。
つまり、カレントディレクトリに `hoge1`, `hoge2`, `hoge3` があるなら、

```
./hoge1 &
./hoge2 &
./hoge3 &
```

を実行しているだけ、ということです。

カレントディレクトリは、`WorkingDirectory=/path/to/dir` で指定しています。

Comment: 期待した通り動作しました！　コード内容について。「Type=forking」を「simple」へ変更するとエラーになるのですが、forkingについて調べたら「メインプロセスになる子プロセスを起動」と書かれていました。これは「複数起動」という意味なのでしょうか？　また、ExecStartの -cオプションはコンパイルですか？　「go build して出力した実行ファイル」を、さらにコンパイルする必要がなぜあるのでしょうか？

Comment: @re9 回答に追記しました。

Comment: cオプションは、ExecStartに対して設定しているわけではなくbashに対するオプションなのですね。物凄く勘違いしていました。「man bash」でcオプション内容を確認できました

Answer (score 0):

`run-parts` が使えますね。Debian 由来のコマンド (シェルスクリプト) ですが、CentOS のはあまり柔軟性がないのが難点。

`/path/to/commands-dir` ディレクトリ下に実行ファイルが置かれているなら:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/run-parts /path/to/commands-dir
```

Comment: 試してみたのですが1つしか起動しませんでした。サービスへ登録しようとしている内容は、コマンドではなく「go build した結果(バイナリファイル？)」なのですが、「run-parts」はその場合でも有効でしょうか？