# systemdのユニットファイル内でのパスの通し方

Tags: linux, pyenv, systemd, supervisor

Python で書かれたサーバープログラムをデーモン化と自動起動するため
[Amazonlinux2でsupervisorを動かすまで](http://zuntan02.hateblo.jp/entry/2019/06/27/205849)

上記ページを参考に supervisor というのを AWS EC2 上に導入したいです

対象の EC2 には pyenv が /home/ec2-user/.pyenv に入っており
ec2-user の .bash_profile でパスを通すことで使っていますが
root ユーザではパスを通すか絶対パスを指定しないと pyenv 管理下のコマンドが見つかりません

この pyenv 管理下の pip install でインストールした supervisor を
ユニットファイル内で使うにはどうすればいいのでしょうか

/usr/local とか共有ファイルに入れ直すと既存のスクリプト等に影響が出る可能性があるので
なるべく pyenv はこのままの状態にしたいです

```
[Unit]
Description=Supervisor process control system for UNIX
Documentation=http://supervisord.org
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=source /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile; supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisord.conf
ExecStop=source /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile; supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown
ExecReload=source /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile; supervisorctl $OPTIONS reload
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=50s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

試しにこう書いてみたり

```
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/bin/pyenv exec supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

と書いてみたりして

```
sudo systemctl start supervisord
```

を実行しても supervisord の本体が起動しません

---

**具体的に行なった手順**

最初の pip がすでに入っていたのとログローテートを後回しにした以外は [参考にしたブログ](http://zuntan02.hateblo.jp/entry/2019/06/27/205849) と完全に同じです

```
pip install supervisor
```

この時点で ec2-user では supervisord, supervisorctl が使えます

```
echo_supervisord_conf > supervisord.conf
```

`vi supervisord.conf` でブログと同じく logfile, pidfile, include を編集

```
sudo mv supervisord.conf /etc/
sudo mkdir /etc/supervisord.d
sudo mkdir /var/log/supervisor/
```

`vi /etc/systemd/system/supervisord.service`
で質問文の内容でファイル作成

`sudo systemctl start supervisord` を実行しても `ps -ef | grep supervisor` で何も起動してないです

> 起動時のエラーログ

はどこにたまるんでしょうか

/var/log/supervisor には何も溜まってないです
（そもそもコマンドにパスが通ってないと推測してるので）

Comment: 「うまく起動しない」までに試した手順をもう少し具体的に記載してみてください。/ [ユニットファイルの作成手順](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files) を見る限り、少なくとも `systemctl daemon-reload` を実行する必要があるようですし、登録が正常に済んでいるなら起動時のエラーログなどは確認できませんか？ / また、環境設定をするならユニットファイル内に `EnvironmentFile` などの記述が用意されているようです。

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile
supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

という起動スクリプトファイルを /home/ec2-user/bin/start_supervisord.sh において
ExecStart に 
`bash /home/ec2-user/bin/start_supervisord.sh`
と書いたところ起動したので妥協しようと思ってますが

サービスファイルがあるのにさらに起動スクリプトまで別に用意するのは冗長なので
サービスファイルだけで起動できるようにしたいです

このファイルを直接実行するのと中身の２行を ; でつないだコマンドを実行するのと
なぜ差が生まれるのかも不明なのですが…

Comment: bash のコマンド実行にしてみてはどうでしょうか。`/bin/bash -c 'source /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile && exec supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisord.conf'` また、[この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/43818/16894)が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: わあ　動きました！　-c ってオプションがあったのですね。勉強になります。　つまり直接書いた場合は /bin/bash じゃないシェルで実行されたってことなんでしょうか？　それで .bash_profile のフォーマットが /bin/sh とかで認識できなかったってことなんでしょうか…

Comment: systemd の場合、シェルを介さないで直接 exec している様です。なので、この場合は `source` という外部コマンドを PATH から検索することになってしまい、(その様なコマンドはないので)結果的に何も実行されないという事になっているのではないかと思います。

Comment: source ってプログラムじゃなくシェルの組み込みだったんですね…　確かに which しても見つからないです。勉強になりました。