# ネストしたシェルスクリプトのエスケープ方法

Tags: bash, shellscript

サービスの起動コマンドで以下の処理を行いたくて

```sh
for e in $(conda env list | grep mlflow | awk '{ print $1 }')
do
  echo "conda env remove -n $e"
  conda env remove -n $e
done
```

というコマンドを bash -c の中に入れたいんですがうまくエスケープできません

```sh
/bin/bash -c "source /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile; \
  for e in $(conda env list | grep mlflow | awk '{ print $1 }') \
  do \
    echo 'conda env remove -n $e' \
    conda env remove -n $e \
  done"
```

```sh
/bin/bash -c 'source /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile; \
  for e in $(conda env list | grep mlflow | awk \'{ print $1 }\') \
  do \
    echo "conda env remove -n $e" \
    conda env remove -n $e \
  done'
```

あたり試したのですが
どちらも 
`env: -c: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file`
というエラーになってしまいます

---

```
command=/bin/bash -l --'EOF'
  for e in $(conda env list | grep mlflow | awk '{ print $1 }')
  do
    echo "conda env remove -n $e"
    conda env remove -n $e
  done
EOF
```

と書いてみましたが

```
Source contains parsing errors: 
[line  9]: 'EOF\n'
```

となってしまいます

Comment: 変数が展開されてしまう可能性を考慮すると、スクリプト全体はシングルクォートで囲む方が良いかと思います。また、バックスラッシュで行の継続を行っていますが、シングルクォートで囲まれているので不要になります。`awk \'{ print $1 }\')` の部分でシングルクォートをエスケープしている様に見えますが、これでは確かにエラーになってしまいます。具体的にどうするのかと言うと、コメント欄では書きづらいので、https://wandbox.org/permlink/oSGYNc2yqWhyELM9 を見て下さい。

Comment: @metropolis さん、コメント欄で書きにくいのはコメントで回答をしにくくするためのデザインです。回答は回答欄にご投稿くださるようお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk をやめれば内側で ' が必要なくなって全体を ' でかこめるんじゃないですか？
例えばこんな感じとか

```
command=/bin/bash -l -c '
  conda env list | grep mlflow | while read e p
  do
    echo "conda env remove -n ${e}"
  done'
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。スペース区切りの１つ目を取得で検索して awk が出てきたので脳死で使っちゃいましたがこんなすっきり描けるんですね。確かにこれならわかりやすいです！

Answer (score 4):

無理してエスケープせずにheredocを `/bin/bash` に食わせてはどうですか。

```
/bin/bash -l -- <<'EOF'
for e in $(conda env list | grep mlflow | awk '{ print $1 }')
do
  echo "conda env remove -n $e"
  conda env remove -n $e
done
EOF
```

`<<'EOF'` のようにシングルクォートでくくれば変数は展開されません。

`-l` でログインシェルになるので `~/.bash_profile` を読むようになります。

Comment: サービスファイルの起動コマンドに書きたかったんですがどうもうまくいかないようです

Comment: systemdのユニットファイルにあるExecStartにですか？それこそスタートアップスクリプトを用意しないと、bashに渡す引数のエスケープとユニットファイルのエスケープを同時にやる必要があるので見れたものじゃなくなりますよ。

Comment: supervisord という python のデーモン管理ツールなのですがフォーマットは同じだと思います。> 見れたものじゃなくなります　そうなのですね bash のエスケープだけできればいいのかと思ってました。

Comment: supervisordについて追記しました。

Comment: 完全にコピーしたそのコードでも /bin/bash: <<EOF: No such file or directory というエラーになります。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61999/systemd%e3%81%ae%e3%83%a6%e3%83%8b%e3%83%83%e3%83%88%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e5%86%85%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e3%83%91%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ae%e9%80%9a%e3%81%97%e6%96%b9 で教えてもらったんですが bash -c に入る前はシェルじゃないってことなので bash -c の中に入れないとリダイレクトやヒアドキュメントが使えないのかも…

Comment: コマンド実行時にsupervisordが改行に空白いれてるのかもしれませんね。外部スクリプトではダメですか？

Comment: すでにそうしてるんですが、複数環境で同じ構成を作らないといけなくて管理するファイルを増やしたくないっていうのと、後学のためにうまく描けるか知りたいというところです

Comment: とりあえずsupervisordの項目は消しておきました。よくよく考えたら処理の帰ってこないデーモンが相手ですよね。デーモンの起動スクリプトをforで回したところでデーモンが複数立つわけでないので、回答としては不適切でした。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103079/discussion-between-ernix-and-kti)しましょう。

Answer (score 3):

`''` で囲めばいいのですが、注意すべき点があります。

- `''` の中では `\` も単なる文字でしかなくなるので、エスケープする手段がなくなる
- 従って、囲った中に `'` を含めることができない

では `'` をどうしたらいいかと言うと、

- 一旦 `'` で閉じる
- `'` を単なる文字として書く
- 再び `'` を開く

とします。

`'` を単なる文字として書くには、主に2つの方法があって、`\'` のようにエスケープするか、`"'"` のように `""` で囲みます。エスケープする方法は metropolis さんのコメントにあるので、私は `""` で囲む方法で書いてみました。

```
/bin/bash -c 'source /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile
for e in $(conda env list | grep mlflow | awk '"'"'{ print $1 }'"'"')
do
  echo "conda env remove -n $e"
  conda env remove -n $e
done'
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。説明してもらったおかげで意味はわかるんですが、チーム開発なので'"'"'{ print $1 }'"'"'この辺りが他の人が見た時わかりにくいかなと思ったのでスクリプトを分けることにしました

Answer (score 1):

metropolisさんのコメントどおり書いてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
/bin/bash -c 'source /home/ec2-user/.bash_profile;
  for e in $(conda env list | grep mlflow | awk '\''{ print $1 }'\'')
  do
    echo "conda env remove -n $e"
    conda env remove -n $e
  done
'
```

シングルクォート（‘）で囲まれた記述の中でシングルクォートを使いたいときは、次のように書くのが定番だと思います。

```
'\''
```

※実機で試していませんがこれでいけるはずです。